# Do Some action after generation of testng-results.xml

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm currently doing some sort of a R&D on uploading testng results to AIO test management tool through API.However it requires testng-results.xml to be generated. But the issue is when running tests with testng.xml, testng-results.xml will not update untill tests are finished running. So i'm not getting the updated testng-results.xml. Is there any way in testng to do some action after finishing the test execution and testng-results.xml generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `IExecutionListener` interface and add your upload result step to `onExecutionFinish()` method

```
public class CustomExecutionListener implements IExecutionListener{
 public void onExecutionStart() {
  System.out.println("TestNG about to start execution");
 }
 
 public void onExecutionFinish() {
  System.out.println("All the test cases are executed");
 }
}
```

Then in you testng.xml file you can add listener as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="UATestSuite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="testClassPackage.CustomExecutionListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestClass" />
            <class name="TestClass1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```